# Can I add a column to Membership Provider's tables to store a user's face picture?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-membership, membership-provider

Should I add a column to users table to store user face pictures?

Or should I create a new table to save face pictures?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot alter Memebership's tables. ***If you add/edit/delete a column of one of those Membership tables, Membership Provider will stop working.***

Instead, you want to create your own table, and make UserID of Membership's Users table as primary key as well as foreign key (which is basically one-to-one relationship).

Here is an example -

[image]

Comment: In MVC4 with SimpleMembershipProvider, it is possible to add custom columns into membership tables. An example is here http://www.itorian.com/2013/03/PasswordResetting.html#comment-form. I agree with rest of you answer.

Comment: @SBirthare I was assuming OP was about traditional Membership Provider. Good to know that SimpleMembershipProvider allows custom columns. Thank you for the tip.