# Adding some fields in existing membership method

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-membership

How I can add a product id in asp.net membership with existing method of create user or something like that. Need following thing with membership like that >>

Membership.CreateUser(Username, Password , Product id ( need a method to add it ))

```
Roles.AddUserToRole(Username, "some roles")

Samemethod.add(username, productid)[ addition for adding the product it ]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Need following thing with membership like that >>
>
> Membership.CreateUser(Username, Password , Product id ( need a method
>   to add it ))

***The answer is you cannot.*** Membership is based on **Provider Model**. You cannot add/remove parameters to Membership's Methods.

In addition, you cannot add/remove columns of Membership's tables. Look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18905624/296861).

### Work Around

You need to create user using **Membership.CreateUser** method. Then use the **newly inserted userId** to add **productId**.

```
MembershipCreateStatus status;

MembershipUser membershipUser = Membership.CreateUser("Username",
    "Password", "Email", "PasswordQuestion", 
    "PasswordAnswer", IsApproved, out status);

if (status == MembershipCreateStatus.Success)
{
    Guid userId = (Guid)membershipUser.ProviderUserKey;

    // Insert product id here.
}
```

***FYI:*** Membership Provider has been deprecated few years ago. If you are working on a new application, you might want to look at new [ASP.Net Identity 2](http://www.asp.net/identity).

Comment: thanks for your answer , its very usefully other, and your more better than first one , but I fixed it by using user name of membership method.